# How to force the server to send back an HTTP error 500 when my HealthIndicator returns DOWN

Tags: java, http, spring-boot

I have this HSMHealthIndicator.java class which does NOT implement HealthIndicator :

```
@Component
public class HSMHealthIndicator {

    /* constructor */
    public HSMHealthIndicator() {

        setServiceFactory(Application.getServiceFactory());
        errorMessage = "";
    }

    public Health health() {

        if (checkHSMStatus() != 0) {
           return Health.down().withDetail("Error Code",  checkHSMStatus()).build();
        }
        return Health.up().build();
    }

    private int checkHSMStatus() {
        try {
           serviceFactory.getService().ping();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
           logger.error("Exception", e);
           setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
           return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    ....
}
```

This HealthIndicator is used by a HSMandDbEndpoint class implementing the Endpoint interface :

```
public class HSMandDbEndpoint implements Endpoint {

    private String host;
    private int port;

    public HSMandDbEndpoint(String host, int port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public String invoke() {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        HSMHealthIndicator h = new HSMHealthIndicator();
        h.setHost(getHost());
        h.setPort(getPort());
        Status s = h.health().getStatus();
        sb.append("Status of the HSM : " + s.getCode());
        if (Status.DOWN.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(s.getCode()))
            sb.append(" - " + h.getErrorMessage());
        return sb.toString();
        }
 }
```

When I do some tests with an IP address different from the HSM's one, I have "DOWN" as expected. But I have code 200 in the HTTP response. I would like that it sends back an HTTP error 500. How can I do?

Comment: Seems a little odd to send back an error status.  The health state has been successfully retrieved, even if said state is unhealthy.  To me a 500 would indicate that the call to retrieve health status has failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should probably be a `503` not a `500`. Your `invoke` method should return a `ResponseEntity`. You can look at [the source code of `HealthMvcEndpoint`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/dce1487424efc67d4a6532ea1ef743809be9ad25/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/mvc/HealthMvcEndpoint.java#L144-L149) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try that